# Appropriate tooltip for grouped datetime data highcharts

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, highcharts

I have a large number of data with datetime on x-axis and counts on y-axis. Previously the datagrouping was done by highcharts on the frontend. I shifted the data grouping on to the server side. Previously when the data was grouped, the tooltip was appropriate meaning it would tell from where to where the data is grouped e.g From Tue 14:00-16:00. Now i have the interval but the tooltip just shows the single point i.e Tue 14:00.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
<!--===============================================================================================-->

<body>


<div id="container">
<div id="container1" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 " align="left"></div>
</div>


    <script src="{% static 'js/highstock.js'%}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>    
<script>
function afterSetExtremes(e) {
var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
    chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');
        $.getJSON(src, function (data){
        chart.series[0].setData(data);
        chart.hideLoading();
    });


}

var country='{{country|safe}}'
src=window.location.toString()
src=src.replace("timeline","timeline_data")

$.getJSON(src, function (data) {
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    data = [].concat(data, [[tomorrow, null, null, null, null]]);
var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        chart: {
            height: 400
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Tweets Timeline'
        },
    navigator: {
            adaptToUpdatedData: false,
            series: {
                data: data
            }
        },
        scrollbar: {
            liveRedraw: false
        },


    xAxis: {
             gapGridLineWidth: 0,       
         events: {
         afterSetExtremes:afterSetExtremes
         },

     },

    yAxis:{
     text:'Tweets Count',
     min:0,
     minRange: 0
     }
 ,
       rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                type: 'hour',
                count: 1,
                text: '1H'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1D'
            },
{
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1M'
            },
{
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1Y'
            },
            {
                type: 'all',
                count: 1,
                text: 'All'
            }],
            selected:4,
            inputEnabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Tweets Count',
            data: data,
        dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            },
        type:'area',
            gapSize: 5,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 0
            },
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops: [
                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            },
            threshold: null
        }], 

        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    chart: {
                        height: 300
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    navigator: {
                        enabled: false
                    }


                }
            }]
        }
    });   

});


    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also i would like to know if the data grouping is right or not. I have used the elasticsearch's auto_date_histogram to group the data. Is it appropriate or not ?

Comment: Hi @samiullah ilyas, You can add some additional information about time to your data and display it in a tooltip. In your situation data is processed as regular points, not as grouped points.

Comment: How can i add additional information to time? Do i add it to the series data ? i.e like [timestamp-interval,count] is this possible?

Comment: I do not know your data format, but yes - you can map custom properties by `keys` option. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xqyonjsw/